# Generate values of N digits among 2 values

Tags: python

Trying to figure out how to do this.

You have a variable number X of digits; and I would like to generate different unique values, where the digits contains only 2 values (like 0 and 1).

Now when I pass the X, I need back values that has X number of digits, with all the combinations. I will have to further pick specific values, but first I need to generate such list of values.

Example:

```
if X = 2, you get 00,11,01,10
if X = 3, you get 111,000,110,100,101,001,010 and so on
```

I recall from my old college days, that there is some sort of recursive way to get this, but so far I don't see a straight way to do so.

How do you quickly achieve this? So far I can make values that are all 0s or 1s, but mix them up is what is causing me problems.

```
# all 0 in first positions, all 1 in second
X = 3
output = ["0"*X, "1"*X]

print(output[0]) # return 000
print(output[1]) # return 111
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = 2
>>> [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product('10', repeat=x)]
['11', '10', '01', '00']
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! Is there a way to do it without use this module? I would like to learn how it actually works; in case I won't be using python anymore.

Comment: @newbiez The link I provided shows exactly what their function looks like without importing anything :)

Comment: @newbiez No problem :D

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it(without any inbuilt functions),

```
X = 5
for i in xrange( 2**X ):
     print ('{0:0' + str(X) + 'b}').format(i)
```

Comment: Just beat me by 4 mins :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that it's a binary representation of 0..(1^(x+1)-1), we can use this:

```
>>> x=2
>>> [ "{0:b}".format(i).zfill(x) for i in range(1<<x)]
['00', '01', '10', '11']

>>> x=3
>>> [ "{0:b}".format(i).zfill(x) for i in range(0,1<<x)]
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```